# Looking for an e.g. bash solution to check English verb conjugation

Tags: bash, command-line, dictionary

Hi I got interest in a solution posted [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/42327/277281) & put the suggested function in a `bash script` leaving at `~/.bin` so, a `dir` under `path`. Then performed `$chmod +x verbteacher.sh` for easy calling from `$` anywhere in the command line but it does not work. I tried to, kind of, [re-open](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/436037/277281) the question & tried also the suggestion of following the above mentioned answer, kind of closely & putting the function in the `.bashrc` file but it still does not work for me (& it seems is not the best (practice (I'm sorry))) so just hereby asking for some more help. I would appreciate it.

Comment: Have you re-sourced your `.bashrc` and/or closed/reopened your terminal?  If so what is the output of: `declare -f verbteacher`.  Also where did you hear it is not best practice to put functions in `.bashrc`?

Comment: The question you have referenced is 6 years old and was scraping a website - even translating that function into a shell script is unlikely to give you the results you are looking for, as html-scraping is incredibly fragile.

Comment: Yes @Jesse_b, thanks. I closed/reopened terminal & did also those little modifications suggested by @kusalananda but still (it doesn't work for me). The output I got to `$declare -f verbteacher` is: 
    `verbteacher () 
    { 
    wget -qO - http://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-english-verb-"$1".html | sed -n "/>Preterite\|>Past</{s@<[^>]*>@ @g;s/\s\+/ /g;/e I/s/.* I \([^ ]*\) you .*/Simple past: \1/;/ Past/s/ Past /Past participle: /;p}"
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the conjugations (on link address, after `/conjugations/` you may choose the language you want to, in my case I choosed french `/fra/` ) values, write this on the last line of `.bashrc`:

```
conjfra () {
    curl -s "http://api.ultralingua.com/api/2.0/conjugations/fra/$1" | jq -r '.[] | {tense: .conjugations}'
}
```

Merci!
EDIT: My bad! sorry for that, I forgot to add the tab space onset on second line, now is correct.

Comment: Thanks Mahanb Hamananda , I tried it but it should be sth missing as I only got as output: `parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 10
` Could you, please check it out?? I appreciate it.

Comment: My bad! sorry for that, I forgot to add the tab space onset of second line, now is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The function (directly from [that answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42320/is-there-a-standard-unix-command-to-check-english-verb-conjugation/42327#42327), with only minor modifications):

```
verbteacher () { 
    wget -qO - http://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-english-verb-"$1".html | \
    sed -n "/>Preterite\|>Past</{s@<[^>]*>@ @g;s/\s\+/ /g;/e I/s/.* I \([^ ]*\) you .*/Simple past: \1/;/ Past/s/ Past /Past participle: /;p}" ; 
 }
```

This can be put into your `.bashrc` file which would define it for any *new* shell started (not the current shell session).

You could also turn it into a script:

```
#!/bin/sh

wget -qO - http://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-english-verb-"$1".html | \
sed -n "/>Preterite\|>Past</{s@<[^>]*>@ @g;s/\s\+/ /g;/e I/s/.* I \([^ ]*\) you .*/Simple past: \1/;/ Past/s/ Past /Past participle: /;p}"
```

This should be saved into a file that you make executable and put somewhere in a directory that is in your `$PATH`.

Note: I have not looked carefully at what this code actually does. It may possibly be further improved. This answer is about the issue with just actually using the function provided.

Answer (score 0):

I found an API that handles conjugations.  I have created this function that will query it but it requires `jq`.  Also the output is rather verbose but I'm sure it can be pared down by someone that knows `jq` better than me:

```
verbteacher () {
    curl -s "http://api.ultralingua.com/api/conjugations/eng/$1" | jq '.[] | {tense: .partofspeech.tense, verb: .surfaceform}'
}
```

Usage:

```
$ verbteacher run
{
  "tense": "infinitive",
  "verb": "run"
}
{
  "tense": "pastparticiple",
  "verb": "run"
}
{
  "tense": "presentparticiple",
  "verb": "running"
}
{
  "tense": "present",
  "verb": "run"
}
{
  "tense": "present",
  "verb": "run"
}
{
  "tense": "present",
  "verb": "runs"
}
....
```